# Letter input crashes program, Only need number input

Tags: c, user-input, infinite-loop

I have two problems with a source code I am writing for my C Programming class.

1) We have to get an selection choice from the user of either 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5. If anything other than those choices is made, the code is to remind the user of the valid choices. I tried using default with a printf(), and it doesn't revert to it. 
2) Also, if a letter is made as a choice, the program goes into an infinite loop, where the selection prompt is continually printed to the user. Any help is greatly appreciated! Below is my code used in Microsoft Visual Studio.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const float OVERTIME_LIMIT = 40.0f;
    const float OVERTIME_RATE = 1.5f;
    const float TAX_LIMIT1 = 300.0f;
    const float TAX_RATE1 = 0.15f;
    const float TAX_LIMIT2 = 150.0f;
    const float TAX_RATE2 = 0.20f;
    const float TAX_RATE3 = 0.25f;

    float gross = 0.0f;
    float tax = 0.0f;
    float work_hours = 0.0f;
    float pay_rate = 0.0f;
    int selection = 0;

    do
    {
    printf("*****************************************************************\n");
    printf("Enter the number corresponding to the desired pay rate or action:\n");
    printf("1)$8.75/hr\t\t\t\t\t2)$9.33/hr\n");
    printf("3)$10.00/hr\t\t\t\t\t4)$11.20/hr\n");
    printf("5)quit\n");
    printf("*****************************************************************\n");
    if ((1 == scanf("%d", &selection)) && selection >= 1 && selection <= 4)
    {
        switch (selection)
        {
        case 1:
            pay_rate = 8.75f;
            break;
        case 2:
            pay_rate = 9.33f;
            break;
        case 3:
            pay_rate = 10.00f;
            break;
        case 4:
            pay_rate = 11.20f;
            break;
        }
        printf("Please enter working hours: ");
        scanf("%f", &work_hours);
        if (work_hours > OVERTIME_LIMIT)
        {
            work_hours = OVERTIME_LIMIT + (work_hours - OVERTIME_LIMIT) * OVERTIME_RATE;
        }
        gross = work_hours * pay_rate;
        if (gross <= TAX_LIMIT1)
        {
            tax = gross * TAX_RATE1;
        }
        else if (gross <= (TAX_LIMIT1 + TAX_LIMIT2))
        {
            tax = TAX_LIMIT1 * TAX_RATE1 + (gross - TAX_LIMIT1) * TAX_RATE2;
        }
        else
        {
            tax = TAX_LIMIT1 * TAX_RATE1 + TAX_LIMIT2 * TAX_RATE2 + (gross - TAX_LIMIT1 - TAX_LIMIT2) * TAX_RATE3;
        }
        printf("Gross: %.2f\n", gross);
        printf("Tax: %.2f\n", tax);
        printf("Net income: %.2f\n\n", gross - tax);
    }
} while (selection != 5);

return 0;
```

Comment: *I tried using default with a printf(), and it doesn't revert to it.* What?

Comment: for the 2nd, id scanf does not math it won't consume the character so make a     else {
        char c = getchar();
    }
if the scanf return 0.

Answer (score 1):

You are using if statement as follows :

if ((1 == scanf("%d", &selection)) && selection >= 1 && selection <= 4)

Here you are allowing the selections value for 1 to 4 only to the switch case.
Then using of default case is not necessary. If you used then it doesn't make any impact.
So remove the checking for selection value in if condition.
Then you can add case 5 to quit in the switch case itself.
Add the default condition in the switch case, then the print statements in default case will be printed, if the selection is not in the range of 1 to 5.
Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Your line:

```
   if ((1 == scanf("%d", &selection)) && selection >= 1 && selection <= 4)
```

is causing you problems.  You're attempting to scan the line for an integer, and failing, so the scan cancels.  Next time, when you get back to the `scanf`, you have the same letter in the stream, because it didn't match your scan and was never consumed.

`scanf("%d"` is not the answer here.  What you need to do is simply get a single character, and attempt to convert it to an integer.  You could use code like the following to do so, or you could take Gabriel's suggestion from the comments, and use `getchar()`.

```
char c;
scanf("%c", &c);
```

Once you have the character, you need to convert it to an integer.  If it was a null terminated string, you could use `atoi`, but since it's only a character, there's a "cheat" you can do:

```
c = c - '0';
if (c >= 1 && c <= 4)
```

Subtracting the character value for 0 from your character will turn any numeral into its actual value.  As long as you're checking the range with the `if` statement, this will work fine.

Comment: Regarding your last comment, he could just as easily use if(c > '0' && c <= '4'). Also, sadly, because he needs to accept a float input further on in the program, I think he needs to scanf("%s", ...) into a character array and then sscanf(), strtol/strtof, or similar to do the conversion with input validation.